# Populate two select from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my JSON file:

```
{
        "AL2": {
                "3810": "AL2GR1",
                "3814": "AL2GR2",
                "3815": "AL2GR3",
        },
        "AN3": {
                "3818": "AN3GR1",
                "3819": "AN3GR2"
        },
        "CME": {
                "2405": "CME"
}
```

I need to populate two select boxes. The first one let choose between first level values (AL2,AN3,CME) and the second one between the deep level ones (AL2GR#,AN3GR#,CME).

My infile Javascript is :

```
var jsonData = {"AL2": {"3810": "AL2GR1","3814": "AL2GR2","3815": "AL2GR3"},"AN3": {"3818": "AN3GR1","3819": "AN3GR2"},"CME": {"2405": "CME"}};

$(window).load(function(){
  $.each(jsonData,function(key, value) {
    $('#ue').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + key + '</option>');
  });
});

function grfromue(element,jsonData) {
    var ue = $("#ue option:selected").text();
    alert(ue);
    $.each(jsonData[ue],function(key, value) {
    $('#gr').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
  });
};
```

And HTML :

```
<select id="ue" onChange="grfromue(this,jsonData);">
</select>
<select id="gr">
</select>
```

The second select box isn't changing, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Sorry. I added some of it but there's nothing really working. My first attempt was almost full PHP but the second box needed to get the value of the first one and adding a POST request for this seems irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below snippet of code might be helpful to you

```
var json = {
            "AL2": {
                    "3810": "AL2GR1",
                    "3814": "AL2GR2",
                    "3815": "AL2GR3",
            },
            "AN3": {
                    "3818": "AN3GR1",
                    "3819": "AN3GR2"
            },
            "CME": {
                    "2405": "CME"
            }
    };
```

to get each value in first level

```
$.each( json, function( key, value ) {
    console.log( key  );
});
```

to get second level values based on your first input

```
input = 'AL2';
$.each( json[input], function( key, value ) {
    console.log( key + ' : ' + value  );
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested JQuery each method to iterate over the objects and the nested objects within them. You can extend it for as many nested objects as you like.

```
jQuery.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    console.log("Object: " + i);
    jQuery.each(val, function(j, value) {
        console.log('It has ' + j + ' with value ' + value);
    });
});
```

If you want to populate the second select box based on the value of the first, you can use array notation to fetch contents of the object. Something like this:

```
jQuery("#selec-id").change(function(){
    $("#second-select-id").html("");
    jQuery.each(obj[$(this).val()], function(key, value) {
        $("#second-select-id").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
    });   
});
```